Axios Post Still Blocked Even Though "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" Set On server
In my backend I've set the following endpoint
router.post("/sign-in", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    //Extracting email and password from the req.body object
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    //const  test = res.json({requestBody: req.body});
    const JWT_SECRET = 'secret';



    //Comparing provided password with password retrived from database
    bcrypt.compare(password, '$2a$12$nAgntW7OmjekzLI2oX1h9u5yPRvQRpenm/E3jhBT1.HZncUpFYsuu', (err, result) => {
      if (result) {
        const token = jwt.sign( 'test@test.com' , JWT_SECRET);
        return res
          .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
          .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
          .status(200)
          .json({ message: "User Logged in Sucessfully", token });
      }

      console.log(err);
      return res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid Credentials" + password});
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(401).send(err.message);
  }
});

Then from the front end I am calling it like this
const login = (username, password) => {
  return axios
    .post(API_URL + "sign-in", {
      username,
      password,
    })
      .then((response) => {
      if (response.data.accessToken) {
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data));
      }

      return response.data;
    });
};

However I get a cors error, I have even disabled CORS on firefox but to no avail.

Any ideas what could be causing this?
I've tried adding the allow-origin headers and disabling cors in firefox

Sometimes if your server doesn't return anything it's still considered a CORS ERROR debug each step anchor check if your route is being invoked

Thank you, your right the routes not even being invoked. It works with postman, just not from the react front end.

Hi, To debug this case, please try this way if possible. Please create a new middle including  -  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
res..header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"), and then load it on the app object. Let this be on top just after the app object has been created. And then try again.
